# Zapp from Square build failure

Tags: xcode, git, square

I am trying to run Zapp from github, but it fails with multiple compile errors.  But the compile errors are for pretty basic stuff, like the rowForView method cannot be found in a tableView object.  I have not altered the build at all from the GitHub original download.  Any ideas?

Zapp Group

```
/Users/cameron_geiser/Downloads/square-zapp-faa7f84/Zapp/ZappAppDelegate.m
Instance method '-rowForView:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'NSInteger' (aka 'long') with an expression of type 'id'
Use of undeclared identifier 'NSConfinementConcurrencyType'
/Users/cameron_geiser/Downloads/square-zapp-faa7f84/Zapp/ZappRepositoriesController.m
Instance method '-createDirectoryAtURL:withIntermediateDirectories:attributes:error:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Required Lion OS.  Fixed the problem straight away.